# bash/sed - adding multiple lines at specific location in file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to automate adding new backends to a configuration file and can't figure out how to do it. The relevant part of the file looks like this:

```
[backend]
backends = backend-1 backend-2
timeout = 10
connectionsperhost = 100

[backend-1]
url = https://somedomain.com
secret = 6135bcb7849ca1886e2de193

[backend-2]
url = https://anotherdomain.com
secret = 75048ad646a5af787cbbaaa3
```

I'm looking for a simple solution to add another backend entry with a specific url and secret.

```
[backend-3]
url = https://adiffrentdomain.com
secret = 42349234238423424
```

and at the same time append the name "backend-3" to the line "backends = " at the "[backend]" section.

Is there a way to make this work with sed or bash scripting in genereal?

kindly appreciate any help or hints!

Comment: Where does the information for the url and secret come from? STDIN, file etc?

Comment: As this is going to be used within a bash script it comes from variables. The information is provided by the user of the script at the beginning.

Comment: Is the script supposed to figure out the backend number for itself?  Does the section it adds need to come right after the other backends (*vs*, say, before the first or at the end of the file)?  Alternatively, can the script rely on all the backend sections to be grouped together in the input?  What can it rely upon about the location and original contents of the `[backend]` section?

Comment: you've mentioned in comments that the proposed answers incorrectly add the new `backends-3` section to the end of the file; I'm assuming your file contains other entries besides the `backends` data in which case you should update the question with some samples of this other data (for both the input and expected output) so we have a better idea of where the new entry is to be inserted relative to the other data in the file

Comment: can you confirm the numbered `backends` entries always start with `1` and have no gaps in numbering (eg, you can't have `backends-1 backends-5`?

Comment: Firstly be warned that [sed is Turing complete](https://catonmat.net/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete), secondly yout file seems to follow format supported by `python`'s [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) built-in module. I do not know that you are allowed to use python and its' standard library, but if yes this might make working with files in such format easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` for an arbitrary new backend entry with `newbackendname`, `url` and `secret` being the only provided inputs. Simply adds the new backend to the `backends =`-list and the corresponging block directly after the general `[backend]`-block.

```
awk -vnewentry="newbackendname" -vurl="http://new.url" -vsecret="secret123" '
  #in backends= line: add new entry (at first position)
  #and set `add` marker
  /^backends =/{sub(/^backends = /,"&"newentry" ",$0) ; add=1}
  #marker exists and empty line (end of header block) is found:
  #print new entry and unset marker `add`
  add && /^$/{ print "\n["newentry"]"
               print "url = "url
               print "secret = "secret
               add=0}
  #print by default
  1' infile.txt
```

Hopefully the comments make it easy to follow. With this code, you may as well just add url and secret via shell variables as `awk -vurl="$URL" -vsecret="$SECRET" -vnewentry="$NEWBACKEND" '...' infile.txt`

Comment: This is way more advaned than i thought it was. Is there a way to managed this when the backend names are not generic? 

As a sidenote the name of the new backends is also sotred within a variable

Comment: You mean if the backend names are like `backends = b-1 x unsorted anyname`? In that case I assume that the new entry may a) be just added at the end of the `backends =` list and the new block may as well appear directly after the `[backend]` block? Or **must** it be the last block? Is the `backends =`-list in the same order as the following respective blocks? Maybe you can provide the keyword that starts a new section after all the `[backend-i]` entries? (e.g. `[general-options]` or whatever. This may be useful

Comment: You are correct. The new section can be added right after the `[backends]` block. The don't have to be in order. There is no special keyword but i can rename them like `[be*customname*]`, as they dont need to follow any scheme, but it seems like you cant use special characters within the name.

Comment: Well, that makes it simpler: now just adds the new block directly after the general one and adds the entry to the list.

Comment: Thank you! This is great :) And the comments are really helpful. Cheers, i would spend you a beer if i could ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try an approach with `awk`. It adds a **backends** entry to lines starting with backends and attaches a **[backend-x]** section with the given info after the last line of the **[backend]** block (after *connectionsperhost*).
Obviously it relies on the entries of the backends being correct since it doesn't count the **[backend]** sections individually.

```
url="www.domain.com"
s=9283283h4923h42934

% awk -v url="${url}" -v s="${s}" '/^backends/{x=NF-1; $0=$0" backend-"x} 
    /^connectionsperhost/{ print; $0="\n[backend-"x"]\nurl = "url"\nsecret = "s} 
    {print}' file
[backend]
backends = backend-1 backend-2 backend-3
timeout = 10
connectionsperhost = 100

[backend-3]
url = www.domain.com
secret = 9283283h4923h42934

[backend-1]
url = https://somedomain.com
secret = 6135bcb7849ca1886e2de193

[backend-2]
url = https://anotherdomain.com
secret = 75048ad646a5af787cbbaaa3
```

##### Data

```
cat file
[backend]
backends = backend-1 backend-2
timeout = 10
connectionsperhost = 100

[backend-1]
url = https://somedomain.com
secret = 6135bcb7849ca1886e2de193

[backend-2]
url = https://anotherdomain.com
secret = 75048ad646a5af787cbbaaa3
```

Comment: This has the same issue as the other solution posted. I appends the new Section at the end of the file.

Comment: @pyte Changed the positioning.

Comment: @pyte, add the expected output to the question; as of now, I can't figure out where you want to add the new backend

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/backends =/s/$/ backend-3/;/^\[backend-2/{N;N;s|secret.*|&\n\n[backend-3] \
url = https://adifferentdomain.com \
secret = 42349234238423424|}' input_file
[backend]
backends = backend-1 backend-2 backend-3
timeout = 10
connectionsperhost = 100

[backend-1]
url = https://somedomain.com
secret = 6135bcb7849ca1886e2de193

[backend-2]
url = https://anotherdomain.com
secret = 75048ad646a5af787cbbaaa3

[backend-3]
url = https://adiffrentdomain.com
secret = 42349234238423424
```

If the input is coming from variables, you would want to use double quotes instead to expand the variables. E.g;

```
sed "/backends =/s/$/ backend-3/;$a\\n[backend-3] \
url = $url_input \
secret = $secret_input" input_file
```

Comment: This works fine for adding Backends to "backends =" line but it just appends the new backend section to the end of the file

Comment: @pyte Please try the edited code